# Why can't a comment alert more than one user?

Tags: discussion, comments

I do not understand this limitation. If there were 3 comments on my answer, and I want to respond, why should I not be able to alert all 3 to my response, and put the whole response in one comment? It seems wasteful to just do 2 comments.

Comment: I believe the author of the parent Question or Answer automatically gets notified about all Comments.

Comment: I know. but that does not help be notify two other people that commented on my answer (or question for that matter)

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.  (I was just pointing out some related information, which I know doesn't actually answer your question, hence my choice to post it as a comment.)

Comment: Ah, got it, thank you.

Comment: By the way, I do think it would be nice if users with 5,000 points could address two users in a comment, and users with 10,000 points could address more than two, because I suspect that users with more points would be far less likely to abuse this (plus I don't see the potential for abuse since comments are limited in size anyway, and also because flagging can be very effective).  P.S.:  +1 for your question because I think it's a good one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's probably a feature that can be abused pretty easily. A desperate user might start mentioning the names of everyone he can find in an attempt to bring attention to the question.

Comment: i've seen this happen on irc, and SE chat. Not pretty.

Comment: per @journeyman I agree; you get two notifications per comment -- the post owner (always) and 1 other person (using `@name`. That really should be sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

[This was declined on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment)

> there's no valid case for "I need to notify a large number of people" -- at least not one I will support by writing software for it. – Jeff Atwood♦
>
> the comment box explicitly disallows submission of comments with two @name notifications now, FYI

So no cake for you

Comment: Large number !=2

Comment: No cake!  Would a muffin with icing be okay?  ;-P